# How to extract a tar.gz file to two destinations concurrently?

Tags: tar, parallelism

I have some `tar.gz` files. I need to extract these `tar.gz` files to two USB harddisks. With the command `tar -xvzf` I can only extract the `tar.gz` to one harddisk at a time.

Grateful if I can be advised how can I extract the `tar.gz` file to two harddisks concurrently. Since the total size of the files I need to migrate are about 4.5TB, this can help to save much time for me.

Comment: Run the first tar command with `&` at the end of the line.  That puts the job into the background.  Repeat same approach for second tar command.  Run `jobs` to see status of both background jobs.

Comment: Yes, run the tar commands in the background `tar -C 1st/place -xf file.tar.gz & tar -C 2nd/place -xf file.tar.gz & ... wait`. If your `file.tar.gz` archive is on a separate disk than the destination dirs, then decompressing the file once and teeing it to multiple tar instances _may_ help: `gzip -cd file.tar.gz | tee >(tar -C 1st/place -xf-) >(tar -C 2nd/place -xf-) | tar -C 3rd/place -xf-`. If it's on the same disk as one of `1st/place`, etc, it won't help much.

Comment: Or it may even hurt. Try with something smaller than 4.5TB before and see how it pans out.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`, using process substitution and its `tee`-like behaviour when you redirect a file descriptor several times:

```
zcat file.tar.gz > >(cd /media/disk1 && tar xf -) > >(cd /media/disk2 && tar xf -)
```

With other shells with support for process substitution (ksh, bash):

```
{
  zcat file.tar.gz 4>&- |
    tee >({ cd /media/disk1 && tar xf -; } >&4 4>&-) |
    { cd /media/disk2 && tar xf -; } 4>&-
} 4>&1
```

POSIXly on systems with `/dev/fd/x`:

```
zcat file.tar.gz | {
  {
    tee /dev/fd/3 |
      { cd /media/disk1 && tar xf -; } 3>&-
  } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- |
    { cd /media/disk2 && tar xf -; } 4>&-
} 4>&1
```

To do if for several `tar.gz` files, that's just (still in `zsh`)

```
for f (*.tar.gz) zcat -- $f > >(cd /media/disk1 && tar xf -) > >(cd /media/disk2 && tar xf -)
```

Note that the files will be extracted at the speed of the slowest destination drive.

Another approach could be to run extractions for both drives in parallel (here using POSIX `sh` syntax):

```
for f in *.tar.gz; do zcat -- $f | (cd /media/disk1 && tar xf -); done &
for f in *.tar.gz; do zcat -- $f | (cd /media/disk2 && tar xf -); done
wait
```

However note that:

- it means uncompressing each file twice which is using more CPU resource
- if one destination drive is significantly slower than the other one, some `tar.gz` file could end up being read twice from the source disk as it could end up being evicted from the cache which would result in more I/O on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zcat` to extract it to `stdout`, then `tee` to fork to two different files, then `tar` them.

```
zcat bigfile.tar.gz | tee >(tar -xC /path/to/first/) | tar -xC path/to/second
```

It will extract your bigfile to "first" and "second" paths.

Can do it with `gunzip -c` too:

```
gunzip -c bigfile.tar.gz | tee >(tar -xC /path/to/first/) | tar -xC path/to/second
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Many thanks to you. I learned about "process substitution" and improved my answer. Guess it works now :) My previous comments are not true anymore so I removed them.

Comment: @mosvy I crawled up in two days to reach a solution I just saw you gave in the comments! Can you please tell why it may lower the performance if the targets are on different disks? And should I remove my answer?

Comment: That's much better now. That's now essentially like mine (second one), though less portable (because of `-C` and needs a tar implementation that takes input from stdin by default), and in ksh or bash, the first tar's stdout would also go into the pipe to the second tar. In my answer, you'll see I take care to ensure that first tar's stdout is redirected back to the original stdout (tar should not output anything to stdout, but you never know, tar is not a standard command and there are many different implementations).